# Anyone know if I can somehow serve a json file with flutter web?

Tags: flutter, web, flutter-web

I am currently developing a very small app in flutter web to accompany a flutter mobile app. The problem is that I have links to the application, and I need to serve a json file in flutter web for android to take the links to the app, the same for ios. Anyone know if I can somehow serve a json file with flutter web?
it doesn't have to be json, any file would do
i would very much appreciate any reply
thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Flutter is a client-side framework and you'll need a server-side framework to serve JSON documents.